# How to Implement Touch Up Inside in touchesBegan, touchesEnded

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm wondering if someone knows how to implement the "touch up inside" response when a user pushes down then lifts their finger in the `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded` methods. I know this can be done with  `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but actually I'm trying to make it so that it only works on a quick tap (with `UITapGestureRecognizer`, if you hold your finger there for a long time, then lift, it still executes). Anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `UILongPressGesturizer` is actually a much better solution to mimic all of the functionality of a `UIButton` (`touchUpInside`, `touchUpOutside`, `touchDown`, etc.):

```
- (void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer
{
    if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            [self addHighlights];
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }
    }
    else if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (self.highlightView.superview)
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }

        CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:)])
            {
                [self.delegate buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:self];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure when it was added, but the property `isTouchInside` is a life saver for any `UIControl` derived object (e.g. `UIButton`).

```
override func endTracking(_ touch: UITouch?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.endTracking(touch, with: event)
    if isTouchInside {
        // Do the thing you want to do
    }
}
```

Here's the [Apple official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618234-endtracking)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement touchesBegan and touchesEnded by creating a UIView subclass and implementing it there.

However you can also use a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and achieve the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I did this by putting a timer that gets triggered in touchesBegan. If this timer is still running when touchesEnded gets called, then execute whatever code you wanted to. This gives the effect of touchUpInside.

```
  -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSTimer *tapTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.15 invocation:nil repeats:NO] retain];
        self.tapTimer = tapTimer;
        [tapTimer release];
    }

    -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if ([self.tapTimer isValid])
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is really smart and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some `BOOL` variable then in `-touchesBegan` check what view or whatever you need was touched and set this `BOOL` variable to `YES`. After that in `-touchesEnded` check if this variable is `YES` and your view or whatever you need was touched that will be your `-touchUpInside`. And of course set `BOOL` variable to `NO` after.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UTapGestureRecognizer` and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and add dependency using `[tap requiresGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress];` (tap and long press being the objects of added recognizers).

This way, the tap will not be detected if long press is fired.