# How to recognise when a finger was lifted from the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view that I'm using its delegate method:

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

And I want to perform some action after my content offset is at some point, and the finger was pulled from the screen....How do I find out if the finger was lifted?

this is what I have so far:

```
if (self.myScrollView.contentOffset.y <= -73 && HereINeedToFindOutIfTheFingerWasLifted)
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

This fires when the user stops manually dragging, but the scrollview may still be decelerating.

Comment: Thanks :) , but if you can tell me how can I detect when someone lifted a finger...untouched the screen

Comment: If you're trying to detect when someone stops dragging (by lifting their finger) a scrollView, then this is that.

Otherwise, you can attach a gesture recognizer and subclass it to detect when touches ended and then fire of a notification about 'userTouchUp.' Check out this accepted answer for details on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830547/how-to-implement-touch-up-inside-in-touchesbegan-touchesended

Answer (score 1):

I suggest your delegate implement the

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

method and have it set some `BOOL` instance variable (i.e., `fingerWasLifted = YES;`).  Then, reset it by executing `fingerWasLifted = NO;` in the

`-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;`

method.